# Phone not getting detected in DDMS in Ubuntu 12.04 - 32bit

Tags: usb, android, udev

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. I have a Micromax Ninja A87 Android phone running GB 2.3.5. My problem is the phone does not get detected. When I try on a Windows 7 PC, it does get detected.

Here are all the steps I followed but still no lucks.

`$ lsusb`
`Output: Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1c9e:9e08 OMEGA TECHNOLOGY`

I created a file called `51-android.rules` with this content:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1c9e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Alternatively I tried [this external link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1475740) also.

Done `chmod a+r on 51-android.rules`. Restarted `udev`, also restarted my PC. Done `kill-server` & `start-server`. But still when I do `adb devices` it doesn't detect my phone.

Here are some more info:

1. USB debugging is enabled in phone.
2. Whenever I connect my phone to PC, it shows a popup in PC:

   > usbmodem mass storage has been connected

Answer (score 3):

When checked the vendorId and productId in windows, it shows 1c9e:9e18. But in ubuntu it shows 1c9e:9e08. So tried to switch to same vendorId/productId i.e 1c9e:9e18. For this, create a rule in /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9e08 and put the below contents in the file:

```
DefaultVendor=0x1c9e
DefaultProduct=0x9e08

TargetVendor=0x1c9e
TargetProduct=0x9e18

SierraMode=1
NoDriverLoading=1
```

Add below code to the file /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTR{idProduct}=="9e08", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

once this is done, run :

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x1c9e -p 0x9e08 -S -R -W
```

Now adb will be able to recognise the phone.

---

For further reference you can go through the below link:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1968465

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this that your device's primary flash space may not have drivers supported by Ubuntu.
Windows is a more common and easy OS..
So your device manufacturer may provided windows drivers.... that's why it's working on 7